# iFrame get rid of white bordering

Tags: css, html, iframe, border

Here is a screenshot to help explain what I'm asking.
[image: Orange is the iFrame total size. Green is the iFrame content size and the blue is the text (not visible in this screen shot)]

> Orange is the iFrame total size. Green is the iFrame content size and
>   the blue is the text (not visible in this screen shot)

As you can see around the orange there is a white border that will not go away. I've included the following code trying to get rid of it:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="60" frameBorder="0" src="http://iframeurl.html"></iframe>
```

and this is the CSS on the iframe web page:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

As you can see I got rid of the margins in the iFrame (goes from edge to edge on the website) and I have borders set to "0" on the webpage including the iFrame.

You can see the white (to the left and top) of the iFrame which shouldn't be there. I included some more CSS in the webpage that includes the iFrame

```
.iframe, object, embed{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border:none;
}
```

I believe it could be the "div" tag that could be causing it (either the div tag for the iFrame or the div above it).

Comment: Border, *padding* and margin, your whitespace enemies.

Comment: @James where would the padding element go?

Comment: You should try to use some html inspector browser built-in tool to find out where the problem is. I would try to set also padding and margin to zero (also for html tag). Do you have class attribute set for your iframe tag? Because in your CSS you're using .iframe (instead of iframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the response! @filipko I looked at the inspector again and the div tag before my iFrame was causing it. I just changed the "Border, padding and margin" to 0 as suggested by @James.

Here is the code that fixed it:

```
.ui-content {
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0;
border-top: none;
}
```

.ui-content was the div before my iFrame. Thanks guys!